# php preg_replace width and height inside of object?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

hey guys,
a php variable `$html`holds the following object...

```
<object width="562" height="200">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/rBa5qp9sUOY?version=3">
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/rBa5qp9sUOY?version=3" 
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
         width="562" 
         height="200" 
         allowscriptaccess="always" 
         allowfullscreen="true">
</object>
```

any idea how I could filter the width and height both of the object- and embed-tag to have 100% values?

```
<object width="100%" height="100%">
  ...
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/rBa5qp9sUOY?version=3" 
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
         width="100%" 
         height="100%" 
         allowscriptaccess="always" 
         allowfullscreen="true">
</object>`
```

Thanks for your help!

update:

```
$chunk = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

        $objectHtml = '';
        foreach($chunk->childNodes as $node) {
            $objectHtml .= $node->saveXML();
        }

        return $objectHtml;
```

says: Call to undefined method DOMElement::saveXML()

whereas...

```
$dom = preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $dom->saveXML()));
```

works fine! however I get weird 
 inserted in my sourcecode when using this..

like this:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?-->
<br>
<br>
<object width="95%" height="75%"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/rBa5qp9sUOY?version=3"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/rBa5qp9sUOY?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="95%" height="75%" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></object>
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is often better to use a HTML parser instead of a regex when modifying HTML.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($str);

$object = $dom->getElementsByTagName('object')->item(0);

$object->setAttribute('width', '100%');
$object->setAttribute('height', '100%');

$embed = $object->getElementsByTagName('embed')->item(0);

$embed->setAttribute('width', '100%');
$embed->setAttribute('height', '100%');

echo $dom->saveXML($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0));
```

You probably don't want the element wrapped in `body`, so do this...

```
$objectHtml = '';
foreach($chunk->childNodes as $node) {
    $objectHtml .= $dom->saveXML($node, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
}
```

Where `$chunk` is `$dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)`.

I added the option `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG`, otherwise if you have `<span></span>` it will be turned into `<span />`.

If using >= PHP 5.3, use [`saveHTML()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) instead.

Comment: @Charles Easy? I guess so... :)

Comment: +1 for using readable code and not (sometimes) confusing regex. For unpredictable ordering of attributes a code is a much simpler approach than regex in this case

Comment: thank you perfect. I updated my question with a little bug. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(width|height)(=)"([\d]+)"/', '${1}${2}"100%"', $html);
```

That should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Is that all that your string will contain? If so, you can use this:

```
$replace = preg_replace(
            "/(width|height)=\".*?\"/",
            "\${1}=\"100%\"",
            $html
          );
```

You can tweak the pattern to allow for whitespace between the attribute, `=` sign, and value as necessary.

If your string will contain more HTML, with their own width/height attributes you don't want replaced, then you'll need a more robust solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
$html = '<object width="562" height="200"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/rBa5qp9sUOY?version=3"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/rBa5qp9sUOY?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="562" height="200" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></object>';

$pattern = '/(<object[^>]*width=)\".*?(\"[^>]*height=)\".*?(\"[^>]*>.*?<embed[^>]*width=)\".*?(\"[^>]*height=)\".*?(\"[^>]*>.*?<\/object>)/si';
$replace = '\1"100\2"200\3"300\4"400\5';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $html);
```

This should work.
Set, 100, 200, 300, 400 to your values.

Comment: It doesn’t work when the order of `width` and `height` attributes are reversed.